# Sequential Sitecore(6.5 - 8.1) upgrade rebuild link database is necessary for each version upgrade

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I am doing sitecore sequential up-gradation at the target of (6.5 - 8.1).

Sitecore recommended approach provided in the link below https://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%206/Update/6_5_0_rev_110602.aspx

On this Instruction-15th point

> 15. Rebuild your search indexes for the “Quick search index” (also for the master and core databases if you have such indexes) and rebuild
>       the link database for the master and the core databases. You can do
>       this using the wizards available on the Sitecore desktop: Sitecore »
>       Control Panel » Database.

Is it recommended carry out the above step for each sitecore version(6.5 - 6.6 -7.0 - 7.2 - 7.5 - 8.0 - 8.1) upgrade

**or**

can i do for target sitecore versions alone (8.1).

Why because its taking longer time. If i skip in between all versions does it affect at any cost.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any reason to rebuild the **quick search index** for each upgrade step. It's *possible* that subsequent upgrade steps use the **link database** for their own operations.

If that is true, it would be necessary to rebuild the link database after each step to ensure subsequent operations complete as intended.

It may be worth ensuring that your databases are not fragmented, this could speed up re-indexing operations considerably.